# Printing date by string

Tags: c++

So i got a little beginner problem here.
I cant seem to print out a string with char and integers in it.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

Main()
{
Char date[20];
Clrscr();

Cout<<"enter date: ";
Cin>>date;
Cout<<endl;
Cout<<date;

Getch();
Return 0;

}
```

My input here is suppose to be :
January 1-5,1999

But all it shows is :
January.**

Comment: This is not a valid C++ code.

Comment: Im just starting to learn c++ so i only know a few.seems to be working tho

Comment: I get that, that's OK, but you say, that you have input, output and this code here, the posted in the question, is not the real code, that you have used. Or this is not C++.

Comment: conio.h? are you using turboC++?

Answer (score 1):

Use getline(). Otherwise it cuts it after a space. Also, do not use capitals for cout, etc.

Like

```
string date;
getline(cin,date, '\n');
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer by @Caspar Wylie is correct but if are using a very old/outdated compiler(guessed from conio.h and iostream.h header files) then try this

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char date[20];
    cin.getline(str,20);
    cout << date << endl; 
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```